# Android service starts ramdomly/automatically

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have an android service, I bound it to an activity, and unbound on destroy. The problem is, it starts out of nothing when the application is closed, sometimes when I turn on the device, sometimes ramdomly, I know it starts 'cause of a toast message. Lets get to the code...

Activity onCreate

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sincronizacao.class);
this.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
this.startService(intent);
```

The code for mConnection

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        serviceBound = true;
        localBinder = (LocalBinder<Sincronizacao>) service;
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        serviceBound = false;
        localBinder = null;
    }
};
```

And on destroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (serviceBound && mConnection != null) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sincronizacao.class);
    stopService(intent);
    localBinder = null;
}
```

In my service, onStartCommand is implemented, in there I start out a thread wich query a web service and insert data into a database, the thread has a while(true), I simply interrupt it onDestroy method of the service...

**Edit**:

Here's the manifest line

```
android:name="com.company.package.service.Sincronizacao" />
```

I'm struggling in this bug for some time already, hope you can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: check your `Manifest` file, if you have ` <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` that calls this service, and in another case check if the `Service` really destroys.

Comment: I don't see a stopService or stopSelf in your code. Boot restarts services automatically. It also attempts to restart services that abnormally close. Depending on how the system shut it down, it may be able to restart after boots or termination.

Comment: I have the stopService(intent); in the onDestroy method, please, check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem... Within the service, I moved the code from `onStartCommand` to `onBind`. I've had no problems since, I just use the service on a bidden state.

Also, previously I was stopping the Thread inside the service with `thread.interrupt()`, now I'm using a flag in the while, and setting it to false on `onUnbind` and `onDestroy`.